# JPA insertion order with unidirectional @OneToMany and @OrderColumn

Tags: java, orm, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

We are using JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink as our ORM provider. The database is oracle 11g.

In our data model we have two entities, shown below, mapped by a unidirectional @OneToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_page")
public class Page {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "g_page")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "g_page", sequenceName = "sq_page")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "navigation_id")
    private String navigationId;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "page_id")
    @OrderColumn(name = "position")
    private List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And a second entity, Section:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_section")
public class Section {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "g_section")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "g_section", sequenceName = "sq_section")
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    @Lob
    private String content;
}
```

Creating pages with sections and inserting them into the database works ok. The only problem is that EclipseLink is generating two SQL statements for each section insert.

```
INSERT INTO v_page (ID, navigation_id, TITLE, manual_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO v_section (ID, CONTENT, TITLE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO v_section (ID, CONTENT, TITLE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
UPDATE v_section SET position = ?, page_id = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
UPDATE v_section SET position = ?, page_id = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
```

This prevents us from putting a not null constraint on the columns page_id and position.

I don't see why EclipseLink shouldn'n be able to combine the insert und update into a single insert as the owning entity page has already been created at this point. Anything we can do to get EclipseLink to generate just the single insert?

Comment: I don't know EclipseLink, but I guess it has no way to know that a section can't exist without a page, as the association is unidirectional, and nothing prevents you from creating a section without page. If you make the association bidirectional, with `optional = false` on the many side, then it will know that the association is mandatory and will probably use another strategy. You could also create a deferred not null constraint, that would thus only be checked at commit time.

Comment: Making the association bidirectional only gives a small improvement - EclipseLink adds the page_id with the insert but still performs the update for the position column. The deferred constraint would be a workaround but i would prefer having my contraint non deferrable as this makes testing and debugging easier.

Comment: @Daniel: You may want to consider ManyToOne as the owning side. A child table contains the parent key as foreign key. Therefore it should be responsibility of child to persist the relationship.